# How can we clarify question titles?

Tags: discussion, title

This was first [touched upon](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/an-increasing-number-of-questions-are-worded-as-titles-is-this-ok) last September where it was decided that question titles need to be actual, clear questions and not vague titles. I think this is an extremely important, fundamental part of a successful Stack site. Titles that ask a clear question that reflect the question's contents are infinitely (I did not do the math, but it's *definitely* infinite) more valuable than those with vague titles.

On the home page right now, there are a number of questions that are sentence fragments or incredibly vague:

- [Make feature layer based on date, problem in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/)
- [KML in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31794)
- [Display of zoomable image thumbnails instead of symbols on maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23955)
- [memory issue when trying to buffer/union large dataset using postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31880)
- [UTM coordinate conversion to Geographic coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30826)
- [Importing Large Raster Datasets in Global Mapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31882)
- [Geoserver SLD for OS Mastermap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21824)
- [Move Extent Locator Display python error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15989)
- [How to insert new line text in popup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31859)
- [Type of Program (more specific)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31868)

Now, admittedly, I am no GIS expert. It's possible that some of these are perfectly good titles, content-wise. I will say, though, that none of them are complete sentences nor are they questions. In my opinion, seeing nothing but sentence fragments and titles void of punctuation looks a little less expert.

It's been a year since this was first brought up on GIS and I would like to start organizing an **actual plan of attack** to keep question titles clear and, well, questions.

My first inclination is to declare an upcoming week/weekend **Title Clean-Up Week/Weekend**, which would encourage all of the community to spend some of their time on the site over a week/weekend combing through the site's content and de-vague-ifying titles. Other sites have done this and also created a chat specifically for discussing the clean-up. **Is this worth trying on GIS?**

Note that editing a bunch of titles on old questions would make them pop up on the homepage, which is a something to consider for a project like this.

Comment: It is 50/50 with the titles - tags are just as important - If we have the time mods and some community members flag or edit these as we go. Clean up week for me family commitments at weekends.

Comment: For a while last fall I made an effort to clean up titles. It was so much work that I abandoned it. I have been pleased to note that some users are starting to step up recently to suggest edits, including improved titles. It would really help if a title edit did not promote a thread into the active category, for then I (and probably others) would be less reluctant to make a pass at fixing up a large number at once.

Comment: @whuber I agree with your reluctance about fixing a large number at once. That's good information to have as we discuss cleaning up titles, and it's maybe something I can have fixed for the duration of a clean up event.

Comment: It's not just you, pretty much all of those question titles you list above totally suck. I too was making a effort to reword questions titles, but other commitments have me tied up lately. A title Clean Up project is something I would participate in. Would some sort of guidance be provided?

Comment: @ChadCooper Guidance would definitely be provided, something like a time frame and question requirement (like, every user edit 10 titles in a week, or something). I tend to also enjoy complicated gamification, so there's a terrifying possibility that I will try to gamify this. If that's too complicated, please talk me down from that :)

Comment: Oh no, _totally_ gamify it.

Comment: The bumping embargo would be nice. One family of bad title candidates can be found by searching for non-capitalised questions, so a dump of those would be handy.

Comment: I've adopted the low-friction low-bumping policy of just touching up titles as I run into them during my normal use. Meaning: if I'm going to answer the question, I'll clear up the title. If the question is interesting to me, as in I want the answer too, I'll clean it up. Other than that if it obviously needs work but I'm not going to add value in some other way, I leave it alone for now (but will perhaps add a comment).

Comment: Too bad there isn't a method to predict a bad TITLE like the [Kaggle Competition to Predict Closed Questions on Stack Overflow](http://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

For questions about software errors and unexpected application behavior, it often makes little sense to rephrase the title as a question, since the question is almost always going to be "How can I fix X?" and the technical nature of these questions leaves little room for writing a complete sentence.

For example:

- [SDE 10.1 Layers Not Loading in ArcGIS Engine Application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32568/sde-10-1-layers-not-loading-in-arcgis-engine-application)
- [Access Violation in ArcObject Multi-threaded Application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/access-violation-in-arcobject-multi-threaded-application)
- [ArcObjects: Memory leak in IFeatureClass.Search (only on SDE with direct connect)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/arcobjects-memory-leak-in-ifeatureclass-search-only-on-sde-with-direct-connect)

Are we okay with leaving these alone? What other titles should we avoid messing with?